# Apply format to flattened argument list without removing nil, or sublist elements

Tags: lisp, eval, string-formatting, elisp, quote

I have a format string with 11 "%s", eg

```
"%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s "
```

and would like apply `format` to this string and the results of `(syntax-ppss)`, which may look something like this, eg. a mix of numbers, nil, t, sublists, ie. various objects.  The "%s" format should be able to print any object, per docs

```
(3 1163 1171 nil nil nil 0 nil nil (1144 1153 1163) nil)
```

I thought this would be easy, but the only thing I could come up was quoting every element of the list then `eval` it like,

```
(eval
 `(format "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s "
          ,@(mapcar (lambda (it) (list 'quote it)) (syntax-ppss))))
```

This seems overly complicated, I was hoping for a simpler solution, if there is one?

Comment: Your question's subject line contains its own answer: `(apply #'format ...)`.

Comment: @tfb yea, I thought I was doing exactly that for like 20 mins, then again it was like 4 in am

Comment: Title is misleading; no flattening (with or without removing `nil`) is going on in the accepted answer.

Comment: yea, I would have deleted it as a dumb question,  but Steve kindly took the time to answer - I think at the time I was convinced that the nested lists were causing my issue so I needed to flatten the list without removing the `nil` elements

Comment: @Kaz looking at it now, the question doesn't make sense at all, what would a flattened list be that maintained all of its sublists!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of formatting the whole list result of `syntax-ppss` at once, you could use `mapconcat` to format each element of the list and join the formatted strings together with a separator space:

```
(mapconcat (lambda (it) (format "%s" it)) (syntax-ppss) " ")
```

The main difference between this and your original solution is there's no trailing space in this result. If you want to keep it, use an empty separator and put the space in the `format` string instead:

```
(mapconcat (lambda (it) (format "%s " it)) (syntax-ppss) "")
```

**EDIT:** If you'd prefer to keep the single `format` call, still another alternative is to `apply` the list result of `syntax-ppss` to be the arguments to `format`:

```
(apply 'format "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s " (syntax-ppss))
```